# How to change the value of an array with a function upon a bool true parameter

Tags: c++

My homework/project is geared towards creating a memory game with a two-dimensional array of characters A-E randomly assigned to a 4x4 array.

We must use functions to do most of the heavy lifting of the program. Once a user guesses correctly the 4x4 visible array positions guess must be changed with the corresponding correct values from 'X' to its hidden value.

I have managed to stumble and crash through the majority of the code but this part is throwing me for a loop.

I have the hidden array showing only for testing purposes. Once completed it will be deleted.

So far the only thing that seems to make sense is to use a few if/if else statements to check if the x, y values are equal to row and column values and if so then make `visibleArray[row][col] = hidden[row][col]`.

But this seems to grab random values, sometimes those not even guessed by the input.

Below are the bool function and void function that the problem occurs.

*** UPDATE : placed entire code to help see how array are initialized.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>



using namespace std;

const int PAIRS = 10;
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 4;

//BLANK HIDDEN ARRAY
void startArray(int size) {
    char hiddenArray[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];

    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            hiddenArray[row][col] = 'X';
        }

    }

}
//DISPLAYED ARRAY
void dispArray (char visibleArray[][ARRAY_SIZE], int size){
    for (int row = 0; row < ARRAY_SIZE; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < ARRAY_SIZE; col++){
            visibleArray[row][col] = 'X';
        }
    }
    cout << "  1 2 3 4" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
        cout << i+1 << " ";
        for (int j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++){
            cout << visibleArray[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

//RANDOM LETTER GENERATION
char secretLetters(int arr) {
    char secrets[PAIRS] = { 'A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D','E','E' };

    for (int i = arr; i <= 9; i++) {
        char temp;
        temp = secrets[i];
        secrets[i] = 'X';
        return temp;
        temp = 0;
    }

}
//POPULATE ARRAY WITH RANDOM VALUES
void initArray (char hiddenArray[][ARRAY_SIZE], int size) {


    for (int i = 0; i <= PAIRS - 1; i++){
        int index1 = rand() % ARRAY_SIZE;
        int index2 = rand() % ARRAY_SIZE;
        if (hiddenArray[index1][index2] == 'X'){
            hiddenArray[index1][index2] = secretLetters(i);
        }
        else {
            --i;
        }
    }
}

int userChoiceX (){
    int x;
    cout << "Please select a row value:";
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}
int userChoiceY (){
    int y;
    cout << "Please select a column value:";
    cin >> y;
    return y;
}

bool check (char visibleArray[][ARRAY_SIZE], char hiddenArray [][ARRAY_SIZE], int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){

    bool result = false;
    if (visibleArray[x1][y1] == hiddenArray[x2][y2]){
        result = true;
    }
    else if (visibleArray[x1][y1] == 'X' || hiddenArray[x2][y2] == 'X'){
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

void updateArray (char visibleArray[][ARRAY_SIZE], char hiddenArray [][ARRAY_SIZE], bool correct, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){

    if (correct != 0){//Update Array
        cout << "  1 2 3 4" << endl;
        for(int row = 0; row < ARRAY_SIZE; row++){
            cout << row + 1 << " ";
            for (int col = 0; col < ARRAY_SIZE; col++){
                if (row == x1 && col == y1){
                    visibleArray[row][col] = hiddenArray[row][col];
                    cout << visibleArray[row][col] << " ";
                }
                else if (row == x2 && col == y2){
                    visibleArray[row][col] = hiddenArray[row][col];
                    cout << visibleArray[row][col] << " ";
                }
                else{
                    cout << visibleArray[row][col] << " ";
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else {//Show Answers
        cout << "  1 2 3 4" << endl;
        for (int row = 0; row < ARRAY_SIZE; row++){
            cout << row + 1 < " ";
            for (int col =  0; col < ARRAY_SIZE; col++){
                if(row == x1 && col == y1){
                    cout << hiddenArray[row][col] << " ";
                }
                else if (row == x2 && col == y2){
                    cout << hiddenArray[row][col] << " ";
                }
                else {
                    cout << visibleArray[row][col] <<  " ";
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

}


int main() {

    srand(time(0));

    int arr[PAIRS];
    int x1, x2, y1, y2;

    char hiddenArray[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];
    char visibleArray[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];
    int guessArray[ARRAY_SIZE][ARRAY_SIZE];

    for (int row = 0; row < ARRAY_SIZE; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < ARRAY_SIZE; col++) {
            hiddenArray[row][col] = 'X';
        }

    }



    //TO SEE THE TEMP ARRAY -- DELETE BEFORE SUBMISSION
/*  for (int row = 0; row < ARRAY_SIZE; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < ARRAY_SIZE; col++) {
            cout << hiddenArray[row][col] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
*/
/*  for (int i = 0; i <= PAIRS - 1; i++) {
        int index1 = rand() % ARRAY_SIZE;
        int index2 = rand() % ARRAY_SIZE;
        if (hiddenArray[index1][index2] == 'X') {
            hiddenArray[index1][index2] = secretLetters(i);
        }
        else {
            --i;
        }
    }
*/
    initArray(hiddenArray, ARRAY_SIZE);
    //REVEAL HIDDEN AREA
    for (int row = 0; row < ARRAY_SIZE; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < ARRAY_SIZE; col++) {
            cout << hiddenArray[row][col] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    dispArray(visibleArray, ARRAY_SIZE);
    int tries = 0;
    bool correct = 0;
    do{
        int x1, y1, x2, y2;
        x1 = userChoiceX();
        y1 = userChoiceY();
        x2 = userChoiceX();
        y2 = userChoiceY();
        correct =  check (visibleArray, hiddenArray, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        updateArray (visibleArray, hiddenArray, correct, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        if (correct != 0){
            cout << "Good Job! You guessed correct!" << endl;
            cout << "You have " << 9 - tries << " to guess the rest!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Sorry! You guessed wrong." << endl;
            cout << "You have " << 9 - tries << " to guess the rest!" << endl;
        }
        tries++;
    }
    while (tries != 9);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to share the full code to see how these arrays are initialized and being sent around in functions

Comment: Updated with the entire code

Comment: `startArray` doesn’t do anything.  `secretLetters` doesn’t loop or retain state between calls.

Comment: `startArray` was what i will use in place of the for loop, and not part of the question.

`secretLetters` is not meant to loop, I only want the function that assigns a letter from secretLetters to pull one value at a time, else it will assign more than 10 values. I can only use each value once.

The question is specifically related to these functions and the subsequent do while loop:
`bool check` , `void updateArray`

Answer (score 0):

After an ephiany of sorts, I figured out the answer to my own question so here it is for others to reference in the future.

the correct functions are as follows:

```
bool check (char hiddenArray [][ARRAY_SIZE], int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    bool result = false;

    if (hiddenArray[x1][y1] == hiddenArray[x2][y2] && hiddenArray[x1][y1] != 'X' && hiddenArray[x2][y2]){
        result = true;
    }
    else if (hiddenArray[x1][y1] > ARRAY_SIZE || hiddenArray[x2][y2]){
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

//UPDATES ARRAY WITH CORRECT ANSWERS
void updateArray (char visibleArray[][ARRAY_SIZE], char hiddenArray [][ARRAY_SIZE], int x1, int y1){
    visibleArray[x1][y1] = hiddenArray[x1][y1];
}
```

I also found an error that was returning strange values in my user input functions and they are corrected below as well so not to confuse the user:

```
//USER CHOICE FUNCTIONS
int userChoiceX (){
    int x;
    cout << "Please select a row value:";
    cin >> x;
    return x-1;
}

int userChoiceY (){
    int y;
    cout << "Please select a column value:";
    cin >> y;
    return y-1;
}
```